# supervisorctl: staggered/rolling restart of processes

Tags: supervisord

I've got a progam with 10 processes as follows:

```
[program:myprogram]
command=webservlet port=60%(process_num)03d
priority=5
numprocs=10
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
autostart=true
```

When I make a code change, I need to restart all processes:

```
supervisorctl restart myprogram:
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to stagger the restarting so that they don't all go offline at once?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way, you have to write a bash command to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @NickSweeting that's what I did:

`restart-app.sh`:

```
supervisorctl restart myapp:myapp_00
sleep 1
supervisorctl restart myapp:myapp_01
sleep 1
supervisorctl restart myapp:myapp_02
sleep 1
supervisorctl restart myapp:myapp_03
sleep 1
supervisorctl restart myapp:myapp_04
sleep 1
supervisorctl restart myapp:myapp_05
sleep 1
supervisorctl restart myapp:myapp_06
sleep 1
supervisorctl restart myapp:myapp_07
sleep 1
supervisorctl restart myapp:myapp_08
sleep 1
supervisorctl restart myapp:myapp_09
```